# Android Activity change causes exception

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm using this code to switch to my class Main_menu.java:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main_menu.class); /** Class name here */
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

When I run this I crash with this exception

```
    03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.CarbonDev.codecabana/com.CarbonDev.codecabana.Main_menu}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.CarbonDev.codecabana.Main_menu
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.CarbonDev.codecabana.Main_menu
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
03-02 10:13:05.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5963):     ... 11 more
```

This is my Main_menu class code:

```
package com.CarbonDev.codecabana;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Main_menu {
    public class settings extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.menu_activity);
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.CarbonDev.codecabana"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.CarbonDev.codecabana.CodeEditor"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.CarbonDev.codecabana.Main_menu"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's going on here? `public class Main_menu {
    public class settings extends Activity {`

Comment: I'm a massive noob to Android. I thought that because the CodeEditor Activity had it, and it worked, Main_menu should have it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.CarbonDev.codecabana;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


 public class Main_menu extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_activity);
    }

}
```

}

This should fix it, please take a look [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) for a good starting point.

Comment: Nope. Still crashes with same exception

Comment: I followed the link in your post, all is good now! Not sure what went wrong the first time.